# How do I know which products have seen other customers when they took a look at the product that I am currently looking?

Tags: 7, commerce

I am developing a website with the Drupal Commerce module, and my customer wants me to implement a functionality to allow the purchaser to know which products have seen other purchasers/customers when they saw the same product he is currently watching.

Do you know if any specific module for Drupal Commerce is available, or can I use a combination of modules that have nothing to do with the Drupal Commerce module?

Answer (score 3):

Yes the feature you are asking after is this module.
[Commerce Recommender](http://drupal.org/project/commerce_rec)

:: Updated, Here is a tutorial on how you can achieve what you are looking for

[Drupal Commerce recommender tutorial](http://drupal.org/node/1465920)

Comment: hi there again!

Comment: any howto or any tutorial about this module (recommender)? Thanks a lot.